# How do I use an ffmpeg device to record the screen?

Tags: ffmpeg, rust

I'm trying to record the screen using the [ffmpeg-next wrapper](https://crates.io/crates/ffmpeg-next) and save the result to a mkv file. There's an example in the crate's github for [remuxing](https://github.com/zmwangx/rust-ffmpeg/blob/master/examples/remux.rs) and from what I've read from ffmpeg's documentation, replacing the input context demuxer with a device that captures the screen would do the trick.

The input context is declared like this:

```
let mut ictx = format::input(&input_file).unwrap();
```

Can I change this input context to a device that captures the screen?